# Getting percentages of random from a method (HW help)

Tags: java

My method studentIsDoing(); generates 20 random things the student is doing at any given time using for statement. I need help making a Summary of the output generated from my method and the percentage that each output generates each time (the numbers below are an example, my percentagess will vary):

```
Kissing his girlfriend 40% of the time    
swimming 30% of the time    
surfing 30% of the time    
etc...
```

import java.util.Random;
public class app
    {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        student st = new student();
        st.studentIsDoing();
    }
    }

Here is an example of what the code reads from my student class: It changes everytime;
Ross Gerard is: Kissing his girlfriend
Ross Gerard is: Swimming
Ross Gerard is: Eating a snack
Ross Gerard is: Swimming
Ross Gerard is: Taking a Shower
Ross Gerard is: Studying Java
Ross Gerard is: Eating a snack
Ross Gerard is: Dancing
Ross Gerard is: Reading a paper
Ross Gerard is: Kissing his girlfriend
Ross Gerard is: Drinking some coffee
Ross Gerard is: Playing with the dogs
Ross Gerard is: Reading a paper
Ross Gerard is: Playing with a ball
Ross Gerard is: Taking a Shower
Ross Gerard is: Reading a paper
Ross Gerard is: Taking a Shower
Ross Gerard is: Primping in the mirror
Ross Gerard is: Doing Jiu-Jitsu
Ross Gerard is: Reading a paper

Comment: Can you format yourr code, and what is the question ?

Comment: My question is how to make tally of what is generated randomly by my method and turn it to a percent for each count.

Comment: So you want to get the distribution of what the method studentIsDoing() returns? Let y be the number of times you received some specfic value calling the method. Then the percentage will be y/total number of method calls. Basically you'd have to keep track of the count of different return values, and the total amount of method calls.

Answer (score 1):

If I suppose every "Students" do something, and that gives a String, like "Dancing", "Reading a paper",

then:

Use a Map< String,Integer > : at left the String like "Dancing", at right, a counter.

Iterate, and keep and increment counters.

Then, at end, make some divisions, as says user3284549

Hope it helps !

Comment: I would use a map but doesn´t a map replace duplicate counts instead of adding them up? Sorry this is my first coding class.

Comment: @RossGerard yes it replaces, then at each iteration, you have to get the value (or 0), increment it, and replace it.

Answer (score 1):

You simply need to count the number of times each activity is observed in the output. You can keep track of these in an array. Each time you see activity #`X`, increment the value at position `X` in the array. At then end, sum the total number of observations in the array. Then the percentage is just `numberOfTimesXOccurred/totalNumberOfObservations`.